plugins for Mattermost Focalboard
My company considers implementation of open source service Focalboard, but it doesn't fully meet our needs. We need a function like Milestones in Leantime, in which you can connect tasks to sort of stages of your goals. And it automatically shows the progress depending the number of tasks and if some of them are done or not.
Does anybody know any plugins for that or may be the way to realize it through API.
Or another open source service which meets the requirements and with good API.
Unfortunately my searches have not yielded any results.
